# 下記ページを参考に２次元バーコード読み取りをswift2で書いたのですが、実機デバック時にコンソール画面の「fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value」と言うエラーが出てきます。

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

下記ページを参考に２次元バーコード読み取りをswift2で書いたのですが、実機デバック時にコンソール画面の「fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value」と言うエラーが出てきます。どこをoptional型にすればいいのでしょうか？xcode7beta5を使用しています。

追記
他のサイトなどを参考にコードを変更してみました。そしたら実機で起動するが真っ白な画面となりカメラが起動しません。コードの修正をお願いします。

[http://swift-salaryman.com/avmetadataobject.php ][1]

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

let session         : AVCaptureSession! = AVCaptureSession()
var previewLayer    : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var highlightView   : UIView = UIView()
// デバイス.
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow

    // Allow the view to resize freely
    self.highlightView.autoresizingMask =   [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin]

    // Select the color you want for the completed scan reticle
    self.highlightView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    self.highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3

    // Add it to our controller's view as a subview.
    self.view.addSubview(self.highlightView)


    // デバイス一覧の取得.
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    // バックカメラをcaptureDeviceに格納.
    for device in devices{
        if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back){
            captureDevice = device as! AVCaptureDevice
            if captureDevice != nil {
                print("Capture device found")
            }
        }
    }

    do {
         captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        // Do the rest of your work...
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Handle any errors
        print(error)
    }
    // If our input is not nil then add it to the session, otherwise we're kind of done!


    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    session.addOutput(output)
    output.metadataObjectTypes = output.availableMetadataObjectTypes


    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame
    // Start the scanner. You'll have to end it yourself later.
    session.startRunning()

}

// This is called when we find a known barcode type with the camera.
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var highlightViewRect = CGRectZero

    var barCodeObject : AVMetadataObject!

    var detectionString : String!

    let barCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode
    ]


    // The scanner is capable of capturing multiple 2-dimensional barcodes in one scan.
    for metadata in metadataObjects {

        for barcodeType in barCodeTypes {

            if metadata.type == barcodeType {
                barCodeObject = self.previewLayer.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject)

                highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds

                detectionString = (metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject).stringValue

                self.session.stopRunning()
                break
            }

        }
    }

    print(detectionString)
    self.highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.highlightView)

 }
}
```

Comment: キャプチャがうまくいかないのは別の話ですので、本当は質問を分割された方が良いと思いますが、`let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)`で取得した入力を、`session.addInput(deviceInput)`に渡すだけです。

Comment: 上述のミスはおそらく`AVFoundation`の基礎が理解できていないためだと思いますので、まずは[AVFoundationプログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/AVFoundationPG.pdf)などのリファレンスを読まれると良いと思います。「コードの修正をお願いします」といったような質問は好まれないと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ビデオキャプチャの処理にも問題があるのですが（キャプチャセッションに入力を渡していない、アプリがカメラへアクセスする権限を持っていない場合を想定していないなど）、表題のエラーがなぜ起きるのかをもって回答とします。

この場合、エラーとなる箇所は、

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(layer: session) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
```

`self.view.bounds`をセットする箇所です。それがなぜかというと、

```
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
```

`previewLayer`をImplicitly Unwrapped Optionalで宣言しているためです。

「どこをoptional型にすればいいのでしょうか？」という質問は逆で、Implicitly Unwrapped Optional型として宣言されているがゆえに、`previewLayer`が`nil`の状態でアクセスしたため、実行時エラーになっているのです。

`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`の`init`の宣言を読むと、

```
class AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer : CALayer {
    init!(session: AVCaptureSession!)
}
```

`init!()`となっています。この`!`が付いているイニシャライザはFailable Initializersと呼び、生成に失敗した場合に`nil`を返却する可能性があることを示しています。実際に上記コードでは`nil`が返却されています。

---

まとめると、

1. `AVCaptureSession`が適切な状態でないため、`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`の生成に失敗
2. `nil`の状態の`previewLayer`にアクセスしたため、暗黙のunwrapによって実行時エラー

です。Failable Initializersで生成するときには、`nil`チェックを行いましょう。